# Promql queries for federated servers

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

Utilizing prometheus federation for kubernetes monitoring.

Trying to change this promql query for multiple clusters:

count

```
by(node) (sum by(node, cpu) (node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node-exporter"}
  * on(namespace, pod) group_left(node) node_namespace_pod:kube_pod_info:))
For multiple clusters, the query is giving:
Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group {namespace="monitoring", pod="prometheus-k8s-1"} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{__name__="node_namespace_pod:kube_pod_info:", clustername="xyz", environment="dev", job="prometheus", location="haha", namespace="monitoring", node="228d5f45-27cc-4a59-b99d-3bab9ebe3b52", pod="prometheus-k8s-1", prometheus="monitoring/k8s", prometheus_replica="prometheus-k8s-0"}, {__name__="node_namespace_pod:kube_pod_info:", clustername="abc", environment="dev", job="prometheus", location="haha", namespace="monitoring", node="3faf3dfa-f8ab-4b3f-bda7-6662c1aa2a34", pod="prometheus-k8s-1", prometheus="monitoring/k8s", prometheus_replica="prometheus-k8s-1"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side
```

Added clustername as external label to the prometheus servers..

Will you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

That duplicate error is coming because of prometheus pod runs as an statefulset. Pod name is `prometheus-k8s-1` and it doesn't changes.

You may need to use some other parameter in `on(namespace, pod)` like uid or something else which is unique at any instance.